# Is there an efficient method to determine if any of the vertices of a MeshGeometryModel3D are visible in the viewport?

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx, helix-3d-toolkit

I need to detect which triangles in a mesh, within a given 2d selection shape on the Viewport3DX are visible (ignoring transparency) as efficiently as possible. The mesh consists of a large number of triangles, so it is highly inefficient to perform raycasting. Is there a method to do this with SharpDX or its HelixToolkit wrapper?

The method I have come up with determines the average distance of all triangles in the mesh from the viewport camera, and then uses the 'paintbrush' method to draw them onto a 2D bitmap. If all given corners for the triangle to be drawn have already been coloured in (or its centroid), then the triangle is deemed to be not visible.

This works reasonably well in most cases, but if you zoom out and the mesh is particularly high-resolution, then inevitably there is overlap between the pixels (since they are rounded  to integers), such that some triangles are deemed to be invisible when in fact they are not. See an example below:

[image]

This issue can be lessened by scaling up the size of the bitmap to draw to, and all respective triangle vertice positions, but this is imperfect as the issue may still occur, and it incurs more of a performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

General way to do it is to transform all vertices onto screen space using view matrix, projection matrix and viewport matrix. Then you can easily search which vertices is inside your 2D region. Then get all triangles associated with inside vertices.

Of course, all vertices have to be recalculated once camera is changed.

Comment: Thanks Lance. I am already doing that, I calculate the 2D position of each vertex every time the view is manipulated. The problem I have is working out if the triangle is visible based on whether it is behind another triangle. I do this by painting the triangles onto a bitmap in memory, from closest to furthest and then checking each subsequent triangle to see if where the triangle will be drawn if it has already been drawn to. But this has the problem of overlapping pixels as described in the original description.

Comment: Maybe check the triangle winding direction after 2d projection?

Comment: Unfortunately even if the normal is facing away from the viewport I still want to include it. My triangles are visible front and back, and if the user has rotated the view so the triangle is facing the other direction, it is still valid to perform the selection.